# Queries on Elasticsearch Configuration and Bulk Import

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup elasticsearch with around 5 million records. Each document has 150 KV pairs. I am using ES 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 with 4GB RAM and 40GB Disk space. I have used all the default configurations of ES for creating index, inserting documents so on and so forth.

Few problems while doing this are:

1) I was able to insert maximum of 30K records from a JSON file using bulk api. I also observed that it works smooth for a file size around 15-20MB only. Can anyone specify the reason, upper bound and optimal size for bulk import?

2) A JSON file used for bulk api contains thousands of records. So every time before actual data I had to write a specification line. For example,

> {"index":{"_index":"indexName","_type":"testName","_id":"someValue"}}
>
> {"field1": "value1","field2":"value2".....}
>
> {"index":{"_index":"indexName","_type":"testName","_id":"someValue"}}
>
> {"field1": "value1","field2":"value2".....}
>
> {"index":{"_index":"indexName","_type":"testName","_id":"someValue"}}
>
> {"field1": "value1","field2":"value2".....}......

Isn't this cumbersome? I mean if I have to insert 100 records, I have to add 100 specification lines in the file as well?

3) I successfully inserted some 3,30,000 records by repeatedly inserting 30K records at once. But then I tried doing this concurrently and started running 5 threads at a time. ES Crashed!!! Out of memory exceptions was the reason. I restarted the ES and found that now only 2,07,000 records are present. Out of 5 shards only 2 were successful which means data vanished! It is serious issue and can break the application. 
Can anyone help me on ideal sharding and memory requirements for such a huge size of data? Also how we can specify these settings at the time of index creation and modify after index creation ?

4) Now after this crash, when I search for a particular record with id 'x', ES returns me the data but when I am trying to retrieve same document with Get, it fails! What might be gone wrong?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't insert 5 million records at once. Instead you should stream the data into ES in chunks (1k-10k records per chunk should be ok). The possible reason ES crashes is that ES wants to load 5 million records into memory, and you get out of memory exception. 5 million records is nothing compared to what ES can handle. 
Try using something like http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=bulk#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk

Comment: @g00fy: Thanks buddy! I am moreover concerned with fourth point and 1,00,000 lost records mentioned in third point. Can you shade some light on reason, logic behind this?

Comment: AFAIR ES 1.2 had some issues causing flush/merge to corrupt lucene indices when you would index a lot of documents at once. Try rebuilding your index with the method described. Also please provide some examples of what queries you run. I suggest you use sense chrome extension. It is very hard to guess what happened without some data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the sweet spot to be > 2k and < 10k documents per bulk request and < 10MB worth of data. ES can only index so fast, so it's not hard to overwhelm elasticsearch with too much data to index.

If you haven't tried, you could try using Node client to push bulk requests to ES. Unlike http/TransportClient, using node client cuts down on extra network chatter due to data allocation within the cluster. It will push the data to the node that will store it, instead of blindly pushing the data to a node, which may then pass it off to its final destination. If you have any processes that take days to index, this could save you some decent time. For processes that take a few hours, it's probably not worth it.